# mPDF - Erro ao gerar PDF | Message: preg_replace():

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

Estou utilizando `mPDF` para gerar o PDF:

```
    $this->load->helper('mpdf');
    $this->data['dadosboleto'] = $this->boleto_model->GerarBoletoCEF($id_cliente, $data_inicial, $data_final);
    $this->data['view'] = 'boleto/boleto';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo',$this->data);
    $html = $this->load->view('boleto/boleto_impressao', $this->data, true);
    pdf_create($html, 'boleto_'.$id_cliente."_". date('d-m-Y'), TRUE);
```

O erro que dá ao gerar é:

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: 8192 Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated,
>   use preg_replace_callback instead Filename: mpdf/mpdf.php Line Number:
>   31592

Este erro acontece só se eu tenho HTML dentro da View que está sendo gerada, se eu tiver apenas um `echo "teste"` ele funciona normalmente.

Estou usando o framework CodeIgniter.

Adendo:

Com base na resposta do nosso amigo Yure, ficou dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta seria a forma de aparecer corretamente no PDF:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que pode ser? Aqui está o view: http://pastebin.com/FZ0apNcy por ser muito extenso, preferi colocar no PasteBin.

Comment: Como você pode ver no aviso, a função `preg_replace()` esta depreciada ou seja, não é mais recomendado usa-lá pois a função `preg_replace_callback` esta substituindo a mesma, você pode consultar a documentação do php para obter mais informações http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: Hmmmm, mas como eu faço? Porque é um arquivo de 32 mil linhas mais ou menos, que deu esse erro... Você consegue postar um exemplo?

Comment: Tente pegar a última versão do mPDF talvez esse erro já tenha sido corrigido.

Comment: Na verdade não é a função preg_replace() que está depreciada é sim a utilizaçãodo do modificador \e junto com ela, onde é recomentado a utilização da função preg_replace_callback() nesses casos..

Comment: @YurePereira sim... foi o que eu imaginei, porque quando eu passo um parametro de teste apenas, ou seja, um echo "teste", vem o PDF normal... mas quando faço a impressão de algo em html e php, apresenta o erro

Comment: @AndreBaill Tenta usar a função ob_clean() para limpar o buffer de saída.

Comment: Onde eu coloco?

Comment: Pode ser problema no meu CSS @YurePereira ?

Comment: Antes de chamar o método $mpdf->Output();

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32167/discussion-between-andre-baill-and-yure-pereira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta usar da seguinte forma para não exibir o erro, mas você também poderia atualizar a biblioteca para sua última versão:

```
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_DEPRECATED);

    $this->load->helper('mpdf');
    $this->data['dadosboleto'] = $this->boleto_model->GerarBoletoCEF($id_cliente, $data_inicial, $data_final);
    $this->data['view'] = 'boleto/boleto';
    $this->load->view('tema/topo',$this->data);
    $html = $this->load->view('boleto/boleto_impressao', $this->data, true);
    pdf_create($html, 'boleto_'.$id_cliente."_". date('d-m-Y'), TRUE);
```

Comment: Com a tua resposta, ele até gera o que eu preciso, porém, na hora de gerar as linhas não dão certo, e ficam desalinhadas, porém, na view aparece certinho..

Comment: Modifiquei minha questão, com base na tua resposta @YurePereira

Comment: Consegui usando tua resposta, porém, ao invés de no CSS colocar #000000 na borda, usei BLACK. Não sei porque, mas assim funcionou. Agradeço demais sua ajuda

Answer (score 3):

Conforme citado nos comentários, o modificador `e`(eval) das funções [preg_*](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) foi descontinuado no php5.5 e removido no 7.0, em lugar deve-se usa a função [preg_replace_callback()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php).

Para corrigir o problema, abra o arquivo com problema, substitua as linhas com o modificador `e` pelo código a baixo:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#([0-9]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return code2utf($m[1],$lo); }, $str);
$str = preg_replace_callback('/\&\#x([0-9a-fA-F]+)\;/m', function($m) use ($lo){return codeHex2utf($m[1],$lo);}, $str);
```

**Baseado em:** [mpdf error - preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use preg_replace_callback instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29432453/1342547)

Comment: Eu fiz essa alteração proposta. Mas o erro que foi gerado foi aquele que eu citei antes.

Comment: @AndréBaill o erro foi no mesmo arquivo e linha mesmo com a alteração?

Comment: Primeiro o erro era nessa linha e eu alterei. Ai deu erro que eu mencionei antes... Por isso